# Angular Material inputs to start from the right (beginning of the page) when having rtl layout in angular 5 bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, angular-material2, arabic

I have an angular 5 app that should support 2 languages (English & Arabic) so I need to support RTL for the Arabic layout, I didn't find any solution to handle the RTL in bootstrap 4 in angular 5

My biggest issue is with the grid columns order in the rtl layout (as it keeps the same as the ltr)

I mean for example the normal (ltr) grid columns order is (1-2-3-...)

In the rtl it should be (12-11-10-...) which doesn't happen now, how can I achieve this ? what is the standard/best practice to handle this ?

I tried using [this library](https://github.com/MahdiMajidzadeh/bootstrap-v4-rtl) to support Bootstrap RTL but it didn't change anything

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jorjtk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) , here if Bootstrap styling is applied, rtl is not applied correctly to the input fields

The problem happens with angular material inputs, for comparison in the stackblitz shown above, you can see the normal inputs in the RTL will start from the right of the page but the material input don't , this is exactly my problem, I need to make the material input start from the right of the page in case of RTL (like the normal input fields shown)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in the question?

Comment: Sure, I will make a stackbiltz now

Comment: I updated the question with code and more accurate & expressive statements

Comment: Can I use bootstrap with material theme in the same time ? is this correct? I have a colleague who said that this is incorrect but I am not sure